# How to convert 2D Matplotlib to 3D vpython?

Tags: python, matplotlib, vpython

I have a project in an AI class that is requiring us to change our 2D matplotlib programming to vpython 3D. I was wondering if anyone with experience in this can give me some pointers or tips.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using the new VPython syntax and not the older "Classic" VPython, here is a link to a VPython 3D plot demo program.

http://www.glowscript.org/#/user/GlowScriptDemos/folder/Examples/program/Plot3D

Here is the VPython code for this demo program.

http://www.glowscript.org/#/user/GlowScriptDemos/folder/Examples/program/Plot3D/edit

And here is the VPython documentation on creating triangles and quads from vertices.

http://www.glowscript.org/docs/VPythonDocs/triangle.html